# the array $data ['image'] is displayed as an empty array, it is not possible to send a file to php

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I need the file uploaded to the form to be displayed in the php array, but I have it empty, why? I would appreciate it if anyone responds

here is the result I need:

```
Array
(
  [image] => Array 
      (
        [name] => name
        [type] => type
        [tmp_name] => C:\...
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 66666
      )
)
```

```
 <form action="" id="form">
        <p>Title: <input type="text" method="post" name="title" id="title" enctype= "multipart/form-data"></p>
        <p>Min description:  <textarea name="descr-min" id="descr-min"></textarea></p>
        <p>Description: <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea></p>
        <p>Photo: <input type="file" name="image" id="image"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
    <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>




document.querySelector('#form').onsubmit = function(event) {

  let formData = new FormData(this);
  formData.append('action', 'addfile');

  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('data.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData)), 

  }).then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    })
}




<?php
require_once 'add.php';

// $action = $_POST['gg'];
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
print_r($data); 
// this prints out:  
// Array
// (
//     [title] => asd
//     [descr-min] => ds
//     [description] => a
//     [image] => Array
//         (
//         )

//     [action] => addfile
// )
switch ($data['action']) {
    case 'addfile';
    addNews($data);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File uploads in PHP are stored in the `$_FILES` superglobal variable. You can access the file upload using the `name` attribute of your file input as an array key, e.g. `$_FILES['image']`

You can access the temporary path of this file using `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php for more information

Edit: Ensure your form has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" to allow the file to be uploaded correctly to the server.

`<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: the problem is that I do not pass the file directly through the form, but through the request, that is, the file should not be passed to the global variable $_FILE, but to $data.
the form is written correctly

Comment: @Ilkara then I suggest to base64 encode the file on upload, then decode and save it on receipt by the server

Comment: @Ilkara Sorry I misunderstood your question btw